# How to differentiate different format of img enclosing tag using regex?

Tags: php, regex

I want to differentiate between the following 2 html tags using php + regex expression. How do i go about doing it.

```
<a href="/"><img src="/nyp/slot/u100/style/homepage/logo.jpg" alt="" hspace="2"/>
```

and

```
<a href="/"><img src="/nyp/slot/u100/style/homepage/logo.jpg" alt="" hspace="2" />
```

Notice that the 2nd html img tab has a "space" before the closing.

Appreciate any expert advice.

Comment: Why would you want to do this? It doesn't make much of a difference

Comment: Not sure quite what you're after... but even something as simple as `"<img[^>]+ />"` would match one and not the other.

Comment: I was trying to do a script that can differentiate between the both. No one got any idea?

Comment: You want a generic one with all html tags or it is just the img tag's problem?

Comment: basically, i will read the html file and retrieve all img tags and differentiate them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<img[^>]*[^\s]/>
```

The above will match img tags that *do not* have a space before the `/` character. So it will match img tags like this: `<img src="" alt=""/>`

Comment: This would not match `<img/>` however. Probably would need to add a special case for it, like `<img(?:[^>]*[^\s])?/>`